# Is it wrong to ask homework questions?

Tags: discussion, homework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Homework on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow)

I've seen a bunch of complaints about homework and whether or not it's cheating to ask for answers online. I understand the general idea that not trying or just asking for answers is not good for you, but aren't the Internet and the community the most valuable tool to any programmer? If I had to name my most important programming tool it wouldn't be my IDE or a book on my shelf, although I have learned a ton from books. Isn't this, in a way, preparing students for solving real-life technology-specific programming problems?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: The `[homework]` _tag_ is now [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).