# The homework tag is now officially deprecated

Tags: support, tags, clean-up, homework

> #### Homework is no longer a tag on Stack Overflow.
>
> Keeping this post for historical reference. --Shog9

The result of [a rather lengthy discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) concludes with the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag needing to go away on Stack Overflow. As far as tag burninations go, this is quite large, with over 20,000 questions to examine. When the tag is removed, it will be blacklisted - banished to the outer realms and never spoken of again.

### The need for preemptive cleanup

Before we put the torch to the thatch, it's worth taking a minute to review these questions manually. One of the reasons why the homework tag is now being discouraged is that it was so often used pejoratively - a way for someone to say, "this question looks 
useless or lazily-written" rather than offering advice or... Cleaning it up. While the majority of the questions are decent enough, that still leaves hundreds that should've just been closed, and many more that could use some editing.

### How can I help?

[Jeff suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated/147786#147786) the following strategy:

1. View the tag ordered by votes, then go to the bottom (lowest voted). Deal with the "worst" 100-200 of these first.

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework?page=1222&sort=votes

   <sup>If your page size is set to something sane, you'll want to click the last page number at the bottom there.</sup>
2. View the **closed** questions in this tag, order by whatever you like (votes?) and deal with the worst.

   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhomework%5D+closed%3A1

**Try to remove the worst of the worst**, then we can remove the tag from the rest en masse.

### So... I just need to edit out the tag on these then?

**NO!**

The vast majority of these questions will be re-tagged without anyone looking at them directly. We're looking specifically for questions that need some attention but will get lost in the noise when the tag is removed.

*After you've given it the attention that it needs* (whether that's editing, closing, or flagging), *then* remove the tag - but remember, you're re-tagging purely as a signal to others that this question is *done*. Only remove the tag once that question is *as close to perfect* as you can get it.

### What should I look for?

- *Is this even a **real** question?*

  If you can't make sense out of the question, or it's simply a dump of an assignment with no context or additional detail, or an indecipherable mess vote to close it or flag it as "Not a Real Question".
- *Does this* only *make sense if you know it's homework?*

  In some cases, an assignment is so contrived that it sounds completely *insane* unless you know that it is homework. If possible, edit these to clarify the purpose and intent, so that they can stand alone - but if that fails, vote to close as Not a Real Question.
- *Was the tag inappropriately applied?*

  There are some very *basic* but still perfectly decent, on-topic questions that may have been closed once someone *other* than the OP made an edit to apply the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag. If a closed question is basic, but on-topic and well-asked *and was **not** closed as a duplicate*, vote to re-open it.

### Why do you hate students?!

We're *not* discouraging students from asking questions on Stack Overflow! However, the consensus is that *everyone* can benefit from answers that explain **why** not just **how**, and *everyone* should be encouraged to ask questions that are clear and complete (and list all requirements up-front, even if they're the nonsensical products of an out-of-touch professor or manager).

By getting rid of the "homework ghetto", we hope to make it clear that asking good questions and writing good, informative answers is something *everyone* should strive for. And if you feel the same way, we're all grateful for your assistance!

Comment: Great, now eat the same tag on meta.

Comment: If the tag is removed, how will we know for sure that the user prefers us to not give complete answers? Though it's usually clear from the question itself, an explicit tag helped. Tag removal may open up old questions for downvotes, because an important piece of context is removed.

Comment: How do we do it ? I mean : if I remove the tag homework when I vote to close, other people won't see it as homework and thus won't vote. Should we refrain from removing the tag until it's closed ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If you don't want a fully vetted, complete and testable answer, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask.

Comment: Note, the `homework` tag exists here (mostly) for discussions about the homework tag. Hover over it?

Comment: So if the homework tag is gone, we probably don''t need the discussion anymore ;-).

Comment: @dystroy If you vote to close, there should have been problems with the question beyond the `homework` tag being applied.

Comment: So what do you mean by "not only in removing the tag, but also examining every question" ? I thought we were supposed to vote to close the bad ones. What are we supposed to do if there are "not even a real question" if not voting ? Is it possible, before we remove the tag, to simply put those questions on top of the "Close Vote" review queue ?

Comment: @dystroy Not all [homework] questions need to be closed. Tim Post is merely asking us to examine the existing [homework] questions and clean up the ones that needs closing / editing

Comment: @dystroy When you look at a question to remove the tag, it's helpful if you examine it for problems _beyond_ just that tag being applied.

Comment: Us mortals can't view the velocity stats you mentioned right?

Comment: We can continue to use the tag on Meta for people asking about the main site's homework question policy. Or, from another angle, `[homework]` is fine on Meta because it's not a meta tag here (as weird as that sentence looks).

Comment: @Flexo Sure you can, every question shows you votes, what links to it on SO and how many times it was viewed.

Comment: FYI: When tags are removed from all of the questions, they are not automatically blacklisted, they simply require people with the appropriate rep to create it again.  Blacklisting has to be requested and approved and is achieved on the back end with a ritualistic sacrifice as well as the whipping of low-wage workers who turn the cogs that keep the machine running.

Comment: The hamsters get wages? What do they need human money for?

Comment: I should start an open source framework called 'homework'.  That should make everything easier.

Comment: Can anyone come up with a good tag set for [the oldest visible homework-tagged question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327/what-are-your-programming-exercises)? @Joe: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ):

Comment: There is an 'exercise' tag.  Not ideal but would work for that one.

Comment: @Mat A good tag set, no, but I've removed the homework tag with a tag that is appropriate (even if it is a horrible tag in itself).

Comment: Trogdor's ultimate homework assignment: burninating the [homework] tag.

Comment: I think @dystroy's question still needs a good answer.

Comment: @David What is there to answer? Remove the tag. If the question should be closed, vote to close it. The two things, tag-removal and vote-to-close are *unrelated*. The absence or presence of the homework tag shouldn't affect your vote to close it. If the question should *actually* be closed, anybody coming along afterwards should be able to see that without having the homework tag prompt them.

Comment: @meagar: The OP says "if you're going to remove the tag from a question, make darn sure you're fixing everything that's wrong with that question." But casting a single close vote doesn't fix everything wrong with the question (unless you're the fifth vote).

Comment: @David Flagging the question for closing puts it into the review queue, which will (in time) bring it to the attention of enough people for it to be closed.

Comment: As an added bonus, this will get rid of about 10% of the most annoying recurring comments on SO.

Comment: @TimPost: _"If you don't want a fully vetted, complete and testable answer, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask."_ So ___Stack Overflow isn't a place for asking homework questions anymore.___ I find this a very sad state of affairs.

Comment: this might be slightly off topic, but: if you got rep from a homework tagged question, and it get's deleted, do you lose the rep aswell ?

Comment: @sbi No, SO is just not a place to ask **vague, general, non-specific** questions.  A specific homework question is still answerable.

Comment: @JaneDoe it depends; in most cases, rep gained (or lost) on deleted posts disappears as if it had never existed, but a sorta-recent change suspended that rule for old posts with decent scores. More info in the second half of [this SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

Comment: @JNK: You've just knocked out a strawman, and not in an impressive way. Tim and I were referring to _answers_ being more vague for `homework` questions, not the questions themselves. But even if that were not the case — are you seriously trying to tell me that the removal of the `homework` tag will remove a single vague question, homework or not? All you do by removing that tag is to remove [a guideline for answering questions in a way that aids _learning_, rather than getting a job done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70155/133368). This will make the web a slightly worse place.

Comment: @sbi: If you feel strongly about this it might be worth a Meta question.

Comment: @sbi - is it really the responsibility of SO users to police students and their homework questions? I don't think it is. For example we don't police questions about NDA'd tech such as (and typically) the next version of IOS. If a vendor has a problem with this then they can DMCA notify SE to pull the offending material if it violates copyright, or they can kick the offending devs out of their closed beta programme's. If college CS departments don't want students to get complete and correct answers to their homework questions on our site then it's up to them to police that, not SO.

Comment: @PopularDemand: [What about this guy?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193478/homework)

Comment: @sbi If the OP needs answers that are hints (with exact answers in spoilers), the use of a specific technique, more/less detailed answers because it's a homework then he/she should simply state it in the question itself. The [homework] tag, by itself, tells you *nothing* about how one might approach answering the question differently. SO isn't going to suddenly become inhospitable to students just because a useless tag got removed.

Comment: @sbi I'm not without sympathy. I've also taught, and I did spend quite a bit of rewarding time answering homework questions. Unfortunately, the tag creates a mountain of problems for each problem it's designed to solve. People being penalized for doing exactly what we want them to do - posting complete and verifiable answers to questions .. just can't continue. `-1 you just did his homework for him!` ... that has to stop. `Looks like homework, tag it as such or ur a cheatin!` .. has to stop. So much about it just has to stop.

Comment: @sbi I'm not arguing for the proposal here one way or the other.  I was just disputing a single point that you raised.  And it's not a strawman, since a specific question will get a specific answer.  If you ask a vague, general question you will almost certainly solicit vague, general answers.

Comment: @Kev: I do care whether some kid wiggles his way through his CS major and ends up at the desk next to mine.

Comment: @TimYiJiang: "If you don't want a fully vetted, complete and testable answer, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask." [Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag#comment421799_147100) _That_ is what I was replying to.

Comment: @TimPost: The only reason it has to stop is because you guys want it to. There is no objective reason. What you are complaining about is called _social control_, and it's actually seen as a _feature_, rather than just an annoyance, in any sane society.

Comment: @JNK: Are you deliberately obtuse? The perfect homework question is a well-formulated question right to the point, which shows a lot of effort into trying to narrow down the problem before posting. And the perfect answer is a — deliberately vague — nudge into the right direction.

Comment: The main reason I would be sad to see the homework tag go is because it is a valuable tool to me when responding to a question.  That tag signals that the question is probably not of high quality _because_ of inexperience, and that explanations need to be on a more accessible level, and that often core concepts are misunderstood.  Removing the door to the common man risks disconnecting StackOverflow from the populace, the same populace that StackOverflow will then need to re-court to maintain a community.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Initially I was somewhat against the removal of the homework tag since it does signal that the answers should not be complete. However, had [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12264970/922184) been tagged "homework" from the start, I wouldn't have given such a complete answer. And without a complete answer, it probably never would have had a chance to get so popular. So in that sense, I do think that the homework tag gets in the way of potential higher-quality answers.

Comment: @Mysticial Removing the tag might be the right thing to do, personally I haven't thought about it enough to have decided.  It just seems that it is a partial solution to a bigger problem that won't disappear with the tag, and without the tag, how are we going to round up these posts when we do solve the problem.  Are we just going to nuke them all?  They have a lot of good advice for the novice programmer, but they often do need editing work due to the lack of skill of the question asker.  Also, too much emotion gets into this decision, as the problems tend to irritate over time.

Comment: @sbi I won't lose skin if the tag (and associated approach) goes away as I'm way past the point where I need to do assignments for a grade. That said, consider this: if I am not in school and *as a professional* I want the answer to the same question then Satck Overflow has failed me. In that particular case, I don't want (nor do I expect, based on Stack Exchange's mission statement) *vagaries*, I expect *answers*. The approach to homework has a detrimental effect on the quality of site, maybe not for the person asking the question, but everyone who wants to gain something from it after.

Comment: @casper: You got a point there, but a so has Edwin, when he says that those you'll alienate by this would make up SO's population in half a decade.

Comment: @sbi Perhaps a *separate* site, sohomework?  I think a physical divide is needed here, with it's own community rules.  For example, not an answer would include completely fleshed out answers, instead of guidance.  It's using a Q&A engine, which we've seen can handle guidance, but not offering up the actual answers.  Then, when they graduate, they know they'd get more of what they need on SO (and probably want to help others in the future on the homework site as well).  I think it could possibly work very well.

Comment: @sbi But that's what I'm recommending, a *separate* SE site.  <whatever>.SE abides by the general guidelines of SE, but if the community there, as a consensus, agrees that say, the interpretation of Not An Answer should be different, then that's generally accepted.  It would *not* be outside of the SE family.  Going to see if I can dig a proposal up or create one.

Comment: @casperOne: Yeah, but 95% of the programmers are on SO, and many of those who can give real helpful answers won't take the time to browse yet another programming site.

Comment: @sbi Well, it's painless to find out, here's the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44531/stack-overflow-homework?referrer=W2Y0drUAn3FAXOBQ42MWrg2) as well as [further clarification](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/7592/14120).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove the homework tab. You should totally blacklist that and tag as jquery

Comment: Does this apply to all of Stack Exchange or just Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan This applies only to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I assume `[I-don't-know-how-to-google]` and `[I-didn't-know-the-question-should-contain-a-question]` tags are out of the question. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Where is Bing in all of that? You _insensitive_ clod!

Comment: @TimPost I use `google` as a verb in the generic searching the web sense. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Clearly, I need to cease all attempts at being deliberately funny. One day, I'll understand it.

Comment: @TimPost That's why I add ;) I remind people its a joke otherwise people can forget to laugh. :D

Comment: @casperOne I was going to suggest that as well. I was against removing the tag (still am), with it gone, IMO something new is needed.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a badge for helping with the cleanup of this tag?

Comment: Only about 1665 left of the 20.000! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework

Comment: I'm actually finding it useful to edit the question title itself when something is too localized.  This highlights its localization.  Then I vote to close and leave the homework tag on it.  This makes it easy for other cleaners to spot.

Comment: @kev: I'm not interested in policing students using SO to do their homework for them.  But I am interested in not wasting my own time doing people's homework for them.  I want my answers to help people, and giving free answers to homework does not help the asker.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that all homework questions with artificial constraints are effectively banned because they are, pretty much by definition, "too localized" - the solution is unlikely to be of use to anyone else with "real-world" constraints (or indeed a different set of arbitrary constraints)?  Is this the intention?

Comment: This is a stupid change. Just like most changes that have been done that REMOVE content. Stupid stupid stupid.

Comment: @DNA: no, it does not mean that. And I'm removing the "too localized" bit from the post here, since explaining that properly makes this already-lengthy beast entirely too long; if you're interested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127720/should-a-question-where-the-question-artificially-rules-out-several-good-options and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132319/consider-changing-the-wording-of-the-too-localized-close-reason

Comment: Also, I feel this is tangentially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115922/stack-overflow-as-a-class-assignment

Comment: This is not a question.  Don't have enough rep to close.

Comment: @monkut On the chance that you weren't kidding, Meta works a bit differently than the main site. Things like tag changes don't always start out as questions.

Comment: yeah, just kidding.  I rarely stumble over on to meta, and it's strange to see "questions" as statements and "answers" as.... comments?

Comment: My two cents: this is a bad idea. We need a *specifically perjorative* tag to say, "we're not going to just solve this for you." I think that's way way way more effective than trying to tiptoe around it and elicit from the poster whether it is homework. Many obviously homework questions already get quickly closed anyway; so not having the homework tag won't do much beyond obfuscating the actually-homework questions that don't get quickly closed.

Comment: I also think this is a bad idea.  This will not prevent users from submitting homework related questions.  Now it will be MORE work to filter those homework questions out.

Comment: @sbi: "Tim and I were referring to answers being more vague for homework questions, not the questions themselves."   To support EMS, I thought the purpose of the homework tag was to signal to answerers that they *shouldn't* just post working code - that the purpose of homework is to teach programmers how to fish, not give them fishes.  For homework questions that are well-presented (copied directly from the assignment itself), is SO's purpose to help the diligent student, do the work for the lazy, or both?

Comment: @TimPost: "'you did his homework for him'" has got to stop."  As a lowly newcomer, I will comply with the wisdom of the elders.  But I think you're wrong.

Comment: I think the move to get rid of the homework tag was pretty well thought out. I don't understand why people are fuming about it. I always thought that `homework` didn't quite fit alongside tags like `wpf` and `java` etc.

Comment: @code4life: whathaveyoutried.com explains the problem.  The homework tag may be a poor mechanism to solve it, but some mechanism is needed (IMHO) to signal answer authors to not just automatically provide an answer without making an effort to teach.

Comment: @Dave I think the fact a question has been asked is the mechanism that should signal answerers to make an effort to teach, rather than just posting the answer. At least in my case, the majority of questions I look at are being asked because the asker doesn't understand (or isn't aware of) some particular concept - an answer that just posts the solution (code) without any explanation isn't going to help them in the future or future users.

Comment: To clarify: If a question is already closed, and should remain closed, then all we need to do is remove the tag, right?

Comment: Congratulations, meta crowd. Another victory is achieved. Better pat yourselves on the back for this. It's going to make SO *so* much nicer and tidier and more productive, when there's no way to indicate to answerers that "you should withhold complete answers and help, rather than just solve the problem completely, so as to make the OP solve it himself".

Comment: @Anrhony: Pardon me for being so frank, but this is bovine excrements. I have said that numerous times in this discussion, but here you go: If I am tasked to do X at work, and stumble over problem Y in the process, then I need a solution quickly, or someone is going to be breathing down my neck soon. If I am tasked to solve problem X, because I am learn something from doing so, then I need a helpful nudge into the right direction, rather than a ready-made solution.

Comment: I must take issue with the assumption that nobody seems to be arguing with.  That is that the only way (or even  the best way) to learn is a "nudge in the right direction" rather than "a ready-made solution".  I can learn perfectly fine when I have a solution handy.  That's what I do all the time in fact, I look at other peoples code to learn how to do a thing.  If there's something I don't understand in the code, then I ask questions about that.  Frankly, if this helps students cheat their way through college, I don't give a damn.  Fix your hiring process.

Comment: @sbi: The question really comes down to this: what is Stack Overflow *for*? Is it a place for *you* to get help for *your* questions? Or is it a place that uses the Q&A format to build a knowledge base so that people's questions are answered *before* they ask them? The "helpful nudge in the right direction" will only be useful to the person asking; people who happen by later will almost certainly not find the nudge valuable. So the question is this: do we want answers that only help the person asking and nobody else?

Comment: @ruakh - Even closed questions should  be cleaned up. When you eliminate all the thorny spots that distract from the main idea, it then becomes easier to see if the post could be reopened or if it really *does* need to stay closed. Also, it's not impossible for a closed question to be helpful to someone. Closure just means we're not taking more answers until the problems are fixed.

Comment: @sbi As far as I'm concerned what you'd need from the answer(s) in the first scenario is irrelevant, because questions aren't just about the asker - their merit is determined by their potential value to future visitors to the site who have the same problem. The additional explanation is likely going to increase the value to future visitors, and isn't likely going to greatly increase the time you have to wait for the solution you're so desperate for, so what exactly is the harm?

Comment: @sbi Or, as seems to be a common practice based on what I've observed, answerers can post the basic solution straight away and then go back and edit in explanations about how/why it works afterwards, so you get the best of both.

Comment: @Nicol: Yeah, it seems it comes down to this — and it already seemed so two weeks ago, when [I already responded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated#comment421920_147100) to such a statement.

Comment: @Anthony: If what the asker needs is irrelevant, then that, too, is a sad state of affairs. OTOH, this does explain a lot of what I have seen at meta.

Comment: @sbi: I wouldn't go so far as to say that what the asker needs is *irrelevant*, but it isn't *paramount* either. That's what "Too Localized" is all about, after all. SO is not about offering help; a discussion forum is a much better interface for helping a person. You can talk to them, ask about their needs, hand-hold them, etc. Every element of SO is designed to encourage the creation of easily indexed *knowledge*; it just happens to use a Q&A format to do it.

Comment: @sbi: What the asker needs is important, but what the *site* is trying to do is *more* important. And if the asker's needs don't mesh with ours, we close the question. Just as we do for discussion-y questions. Just as we do for poll questions. Just as we do for broad, beginner questions like "how do I make a web-page". And other such things. None of those creates viable information that will be of value in the future, so we shut them down.

Comment: @sbi: Personally, my main concern is not that SO will not be the place to ask homework questions. It's that it ***will be*** the place to ask homework questions. That people will ask, untagged, and people will answer before any bad questions are closed. That SO users will be unwittingly suborning academic dishonesty. SO should *never* have been a place for homework questions to begin with, but since they're inevitable, at least having the homework tag lessened the chance of someone helping someone cheat.

Comment: Frankly, this argument is mostly irrelevant - regardless of the *intent*, the tag does nothing to stop complete answers and precious little to encourage "pedagogical" answers. The folks willing to hand over a complete answer tend to find themselves rewarded (particularly when that's all the asker wants), while the folks willing to teach tend to have to suss out the presence of homework *anyway*. Maybe the tag worked better when SO was smaller; maybe a sufficiently-small, sufficiently dedicated community could still make it work. But from what I've seen, good intentions aren't going far here.

Comment: Just to clarify - for already-closed questions that can't be salvaged, should we remove the tag so the effort of checking doesn't get repeated by someone else? Or should we leave them for the automated un-tagging?

Comment: @J20 You can just remove the tag and flag the post as 'Very Low Quality'. This tells us that you think the question can't be salvaged with a normal amount of editing and should probably be removed. You can also flag as 'other' and indicate that you removed the tag as part of the cleanup and think the question should probably get a proper burial. Either way, if we agree that it can't be salvaged, off it goes. Once in a while, if a bad question got _great_ answers, we try our best to salvage it, but your flag should still be validated if the post was extremely problematic.

Comment: "`Looks like homework, tag it as such or ur a cheatin!` .. has to stop.  So much about it just has to stop."  First, it is not written that I should comprehend everything.  Second, I am not (and do not wish to be) a moderator, so I do not understand or sympathize.   However, for what it's worth, since you ask, I do not grasp your motive.  The utility of the `homework` tag is clear to me.  The problems associated with it are not.

Comment: @Shog: __Regardless of the__ ___intent,___ __the tag removal does nothing to solve any of the problem homework questions come with, while it does create the problem that they are harder to, well,__ ___tag.___ So far, and in the more than two weeks since I first wrote this here, nobody has come up with any evidence that removing the tag would solve any of the problems. However, due to you guys repeating the same non-arguments, we are just going in circles, and I am now tired of doing so, which is why I will now stop repeating myself here, and bow out of the discussion.

Comment: "Only remove the tag once that question is as close to perfect as you can get it." Can you elaborate a bit more on that in the question? I see *a lot* of edits in my review queue where just the tag is removed, and the question is "Okay-ish" but *could* still be improved. Most of those get approved by others will I sit and ponder what to do (i.e. most folks in the community seem to think it was ok).

Comment: Sorry, but this is horse poopy. There are way more instances of the "elite" pushing the homework issue, which people tend not to tag as already because of the scrutiny, and lack of answers. That's not the posters fault, that's the fault of those who want to make an example out of less knowledgeable folks. If you remove the tag, all the people who already question if it's homework or not will disregard the question based on suspicion. I hope you add a new feature that auto-deletes all the I'm not sure if this is homework comments you're about to get. I won't be sending peers here anymore!,.|..

Comment: The cleanup has just stopeed little by little in time. After the few thusand questions have been handled, for the last week things are very slow. There are stil 14000 questions taged `homework`. Shouldn't the community be more involved? Just saying in an old meta questions that the tag is deprecated seems not enough.

Comment: @CoralDoe The problem is they come in at such a high volume, it's like chasing our tail. We're talking about what to do about that now.

Comment: @TimPost: It is clear to me that it is a high volume of work for moderators only, I was asking about things to envolve the whole community. When this meta questions was visible in the left on stackoverflow people could be reminded of this clean-up. Now it seems that most just forgot.

Answer (score 58):

Here's an idea, why don't we ask SE to tweak the new review queue and route all the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) questions through there (note, I'm not asking for a tool that let's moderators do this, that opens the door to abuse, but rather, I want them to manually tweak the algorithm/flags/whatever to run that set of questions through the queue)?  We'll certainly get the closures quicker and ensure coverage of all those questions.

Once the queue is cleared again (which should be quick, because we'll have all of the people who use that queue, not just people who are always on meta and willing to do something about it), the tag can be nuked from orbit, knowing that all the questions with the tag had been properly vetted.

The blacklist could then be applied.

Easy-peasy.  Let's do it.

Comment: What (if any) ramifications would surface if mods could just suggest a tag to review? That's going to come up as a slippery slope.

Comment: I don't think so. If a mod put a tag up for review, and there had not been consensus on Meta beforehand, I would assume there would be pitchforks waiting for said mod on Meta. At which point the SE team could step in to help clear it up. It is a matter of trusting the mods to do their jobs, while at the same time trusting there is a recourse for action if one happens to stray off the path.

Comment: @TimPost If we suggest it on Meta, it's pretty transparent, I'm not worried about that case.  If we suggest it through other channels and it happens, well, that would be an issue, but I assume SE would shut us down because of the lack of transparency and route us back to meta.  Note, I'm not asking that mods be given a tool to indicate   what questions should be routed through the review queue by tag, I'm saying SE should do whatever they do to route this particular set of questions through the queue at our behest for this purpose.

Comment: Consider yourself shut down and routed back to meta. ;) (Seriously, though, I find the idea of tag-based review queues intriguing in principle. Need to think more about it and/or see a fleshed out proposal before forming a strong opinion one way or another.)

Comment: @AnnaLear - I kind of like the idea of special job queues that appear periodically to quickly sort out a problem. There could be a badge for taking part for each one. And community feels good about itself for being part of a task force when needed.

Comment: I definitely like the idea. Additionally, those that follow a tag (but perhaps not meta) could be informed of coordinated tag efforts in their global inbox. The queue would need to be a bit different though, as each effort would presumably have some guidance to read and follow.

Answer (score 45):

If only we could find a way to embed one of these into the final product of everyone who posts on the homework tag.

[image]

Comment: Lulz, I would see that on some classmate's assignments.

Comment: ... Add some strange invisible unicode letters in a comment, so they get copypasted with the code? ;-)

Comment: Can we add such a stamp on all answers to questions of professionals who actually earn their living by asking questions on SE. In contrast to the scholars, they are actually expeced to know or to be able to find the answers themselves.

Comment: @GolezTrol - Sometimes finding the answers yourself involves asking specific questions about a certain piece of the puzzle so that one might take that information and work towards a more complete solution. For instance, I asked and got tips on how to get Objective C and C++ to work together, but with the answers I got I'm nowhere near done. I still have to make all my code work together.  In short, asking for help is just as important for a professional to do as it is to know how to dig in and try to solve problems yourself. :)

Comment: Sure, but *some* of those questions (too many, I must say), lack that professional attitude. Anyway, I said this in context of this 'anti-homework-tag' thread. I see in many places on the internet, including here on SE, that asking homework questions is frowned upon, but I don't really see the difference between a scholar asking questions and a professional asking questions, apart from the difference in salary, of course. ;) Not saying that asking questions is at all bad.

Comment: @GolezTrol - The questions asked by "scholars" are mundane, trivial and repetitive.

Comment: @GolezTrol That's ludicrous, you're putting scholars above others because someone else had already asked and answered the question they're about to ask. Instead of answers on SE and the last few decades etc, they've got all of human history to refer to. Not an fair comparison, I don't think.

Comment: I'm not putting scholars above others, and neither do I say that questions by scholars aren't trivial and repetitive. I *do* say that most questions on SO are just that, not only those by scholars. I daresay that at least 90% of the questions could be fairly easily answered and are answered before on SO or elswhere on the internet. You'd be surprised how much rep you could gain by writing a bot that pastes the title of every new question into Google, and pastes the first result as an answer. I don't like it if students ask those stupid questions, but I hate it when professionals do.

Answer (score 30):

With a big tag that needs cleanup, I do two things to triage, and I'd suggest the same with [homework](/questions/tagged/homework)

1. View the tag ordered by votes, then go to the bottom (lowest voted). Deal with the "worst" 100-200 of these first.

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework?page=1222&sort=votes
2. View the **closed** questions in this tag, order by whatever you like (votes?) and deal with the worst.

   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhomework%5D+closed%3A1

The best thing to do is **deal with the bottom of the barrel first, try to remove the worst of the worst**, then burninate the rest as at least not-harmful.

Comment: So the assumption is "More than likely, if there are a number of upvotes on the question already, the question is a safe candidate for blind removal of the tag"?

Answer (score 25):

YES!

I don't see how this review-and-remove can work if the tag isn't blacklisted. It's going to be added again and again to new questions. If the tag was blacklisted, editing a question tagged [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), for any reason, would require removing the tag. I think that's ok. There are plenty of “homeworky” (and non-homeworky) questions in need of closing that don't have the homework tag anyway.

I don't think there's anything to be gained by not burninating the tag right away. Part of the reason the tag is useless is that it does not categorize questions in any meaningful way. The probability that a [homework](/questions/tagged/homework)-tagged question needs reviewing is higher than average but not dramatically so.

Comment: Oh no, it's not coming back after this.

Comment: Can we actually blacklist it *without* removing it from all the questions though?

Comment: @BenBrocka Can you break dance safely in an event horizon? Yeah, I'm not trying that either.

Comment: @Ben It is extremely messy and will cause a lot of fuss because people will see that "homework" totally exists, but when they try to use it, they can't, which is weird because there's thousands of questions that have it. That's one of the more relevant reasonings why we don't blacklist live tags - it creates a lot of mess that gets in the way of doing the cleanup.

Comment: @GraceNote that makes sense...I just figured blacklisting implicitly deleted the tag as well, since it doesn't make sense to have an unusable tag that still exists.

Comment: @GraceNote: but listening to the whining and gnashing of teeth is satisfying when you vote to close...

Comment: @TimPost Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/651486

Comment: @Gilles Title edit made, just FYI.

Comment: @GraceNote - It may cause some confusion to blacklist it now, but I worry about just leaving it enabled. I've been actively hunting homeworks for a few days, and about once every hour or two I see at least one new homework question posted, or an old question that's been retagged as homework. Given that after 3 days we've only touched something like 5% of total homework questions, I'm afraid most active retaggers will burn out, and the count might start creeping up again. It takes a lot of vigilance just to tread in place.

Comment: @TimPost - "Can you break dance safely in an event horizon?" - you should ask that on Physics SE :)

Answer (score 14):

I've been working on the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) question cleanup. To help, I created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80291/tags-associated-with-homework-tag-ordered-by-question-count) that lists all the tags associated with questions tagged [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), sorted by question count.

What I do is:

1. Pick a small-ish tag of a dozen or so questions, such as [masm](/questions/tagged/masm).
2. Search for [`[homework] [masm]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework+masm) to show all those questions.
3. For each of those questions:
4. Flag any *This should have the homework tag!!1!* comments as **obsolete**.
5. If the question is perfectly fine without [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), remove the tag. (I try to add a more specific tag in its place, depending on the question topic).
6. If the question is not a real question (eg. verbatim homework dump) or too localized (eg. "you forgot a closing brace"), vote to close the question as necessary and *leave the homework tag in place*.

The above ensures that others who are searching for [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) questions will also see those that still need attention.

In just a couple of days, we have nailed nearly 5% of the homework questions. This is doable, but it will take a while.

Comment: Should the tag be removed once the question is closed, or do we want to keep it as a marker for deletions, too?

Comment: I would say leave the tag attached after closing, so that those questions can be readily found for deletion.

Comment: Removing the tag is rather important once you are able to do so, because it decreases the time it will take to reach zero (or few) tagged questions, at which point we can blacklist the tag to keep new questions from using it. Presumably, if something is ready for the bit bucket, the deletion cycle would be not unlike any other poor question.

Comment: We really need a way to _deprecate_ a tag so that people can't apply it any longer while explaining to them why they can't add an existing tag.

Answer (score 14):

There's a lot of good commentary, but one point that was raised doesn't sit right with me.

> Will this question help anyone else but the person who asked it?

This is predicting the future.  While there is "low hanging fruit" on the question tree that applies to nearly everyone, there is also room for questions that seem to apply to only a single person.  I don't want StackOverflow to be only a "greatest hits" question repository, as we often see that popularity doesn't breed an ideal world (for whatever measure you are seeking).

Also it implies that you can *predict* a question's future utility, or that you can measure that utility based on StackOverflow's captured metrics (which are not gathered in the blind and are subject to gaming).

It also shifts StackOverflow from a resource where one can part-time mentor a new software developer into a resource for seasoned professionals.  Yes, we have tons of entry points for fresh meat, but those new recruits to the field need to be acclimated to StackOverflow's way of doing things *after* they attempt to use StackOverflow.  It would be nice if it worked the other way around, but the complaints about "what you are supposed to do" are proof that there is an acclimation period that trials first SO use.

I don't think that this criteria is well thought out, and it seems to be a weak point.  Kill the homework tag if you wish, but don't confound utility of the question and answers with popular utility of the question and answers.

Comment: By that, I was saying you should ask "Is this question _too localized_?" Which is one of the reasons why a question can be closed, currently in place on Stack Overflow. I've edited for clarity, and included the definition given for the close reason as reference.

Comment: A much better way of stating it, and like all elegant software development, the new solution comes from a reduction in items, but more power in their expressiveness.

Answer (score 13):

**Could people please stop asking for mass deletion of the homework tag?**

I want it gone just as much as anyone else but.... even a quick look will show you that there are a lot of these questions that are inappropriately tagged, even once `homework` is removed. That means these questions need some tender McLovin'. There are a whole bunch of questions just labelled [c](/questions/tagged/c) [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) (and some that also contain a third random-ish tag), so just blowing away the `homework` tag will leave these questions balancing precariously on the edge of the tag universe.

We should also be flagging the `Is this homework?` or `You need to tag this as homework` comments as part of the clean up. These comments are redundant now that the tag has entered burnination.

Comment: Flag the comments on the questions you think are salvageable or have been salvaged, but don't worry _as much_ about comments on something probably headed for the bin. It'll help keep the signal to noise ratio in our queue higher during the cleanup.

Comment: @TimPost I think slugster's probably mostly thinking about comments on posts that aren't tagged [homework].

Answer (score 2):

A quick search shows that there are [1,809 homework questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhomework%5D+closed%3A1&submit=search) which are **already closed**. That's almost a tenth of the 20,000 total [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) questions. Can we possibly get a mass-untagging of any closed homework questions?

Comment: Or a mass deletion?

Comment: If the mods all agree that that's an acceptable solution, then by all means.

Comment: The already-closed questions need to be reviewed for reopening. Granted, most of them aren't going to be reopened (and should therefore be deleted), but statistically speaking a few of them have been edited into shape, or have been mistagged (perhaps maliciously by another user!), and should be reopened. Cc @BilltheLizard

Comment: @Gilles Good point.  I guess we do have to look at them individually.

Comment: This is a good option for the ones that are zero upvotes and no upvoted answers.

Comment: Any perfectly valid, reasonably well written but extremely basic question should not be closed unless it's a duplicate of another. Those are going to need individual review, but many questions closed 'because they look like homework' could have probably been closed because they were simply duplicates. I'm not saying don't examine them, but don't go agonizing over them. The tag needs to be removed, either way and if you run into salvageable stuff .. well, great :)

Comment: I think correct time for this mass untaging would be when query for "homework" tag returns only closed question. Until then tag is still useful because it points to questions that need reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

With this answer, I am suggesting a feature-request (a kind of).

We would have such situations in future that would require a clean up for tags. Can we **some-what** automate this? 
I suggest create a tag (may be 'cleaned-up' or '.' (dot)) as a master tag, and then, if you could make 'all such tags to be cleaned up' as synonyms  to this master tag.

And then, make some rule at back-end to just not display such tags any more, or do any other appropriate thing like close the post/put into moderator review queue, or ??

This would save much of the effort and time. I mean - all the active users would do this respectfully try to action them at their end as much as they can, but 17,000 + questions is a huge number. And as this process has started, we see a lot of old questions dumping in the front.

Comment: Sounds like what [casperOne already proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147116). That will bump the questions — SE has never accepted anything that would modify a question without bumping, except outright removal of a tag, which is performed by a developer. There's no harm in bumping old questions now and then — as long as the front page isn't flooded, which can't happen on SO.