# The use of [big] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are 83 questions tagged [big](/questions/tagged/big) (latest one was asked 4 days back). Is there any use of [big](/questions/tagged/big) on Stack Overflow? I think it should be deleted.

Comment: +1 agree with you, this tag is totally non-IT term.

Comment: Some of these questions are related to big-O notation, and so should be retagged as [tag:big-o].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a great candidate for burniation.

The same goes for [huge](/questions/tagged/huge) (82). And there are probably more, but I'm out of synonyms for big and small.

Comment: Presumably some questions tagged huge can be retagged as [tag:large-files] or [tag:large-data], or are these tags just as bad as [tag:huge]?

Comment: @Chris: I think they are slightly better than [tag:big] or [tag:huge]. Not great, but they carry at least some information that binds the questions together.

Comment: out of curiosity I searched for `enormous` and `gigantic` as well, luckily (or not) there were none

Comment: @prusswan I guess these 2 words are tough to spell as compared to `big` and `huge` which is why no one used them :)

Comment: but...there was actually one for [tag:massive]!

Answer (score 6):

With [only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) 83 questions, these can be reviewed manually.

Besides [huge](/questions/tagged/huge), there are also [major](/questions/tagged/major) and [minor](/questions/tagged/minor), and quite a few `large-*`, some of which are good ([large-files](/questions/tagged/large-files)), others not. Also [tiny](/questions/tagged/tiny), but at least some of these are about something called “tiny”: again, to be reviewed manually.

Remove the tag from a question if it does not carry any meaning. Retag the question if necessary.

Comment: If we manually remove tags then will those questions be bumped to the top of the questions list? If that is the case then 83 old questions coming up on first screen would not look good.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Yes, they will be bumped. On [so] this is not a problem, 83 questions is 20 minutes' worth of new questions (and about 3 or 4 minutes' worth of new answers and edits). The SO home page is filtered to present “interesting” questions which further reduces the front page. On other Stack Exchange sites, such bumping would indeed be a problem.