# Unwanted tags: [old], [yes-no], [huge], [same]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are some questions tagged [old](/questions/tagged/old), [yes-no](/questions/tagged/yes-no)(atleast renamed), [huge](/questions/tagged/huge),[issues](/questions/tagged/issues) and [same](/questions/tagged/same).

some more are [city](/questions/tagged/city),[country](/questions/tagged/country) these are usualy related with GeoLocation so should renamed to [geo-location-city](/questions/tagged/geo-location-city) and [geo-location-country](/questions/tagged/geo-location-country)

Is there any use of these on StackOverflow? I think these should be deleted.

Comment: [tag:old]: Yes. [tag:huge]: Yes. [tag:same]: Yes. However, [tag:yes-no]: No. Yes-no refers to the yes-no dialog box in VB, which is very specifc. The tag should definitely be cleaned up, though.

Comment: @Telthien: If it really is that important, it should probably be renamed, or at least made a synonym of something clearer. [yes-no] by itself is a really lousy name for a tag.

Comment: this is funny, because I am sure `huge` has been removed before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147476/166277

Comment: @prusswan I guess that's one of those situations where everybody talked about them, but nobody did anything.

Comment: Looks like [old] was never actually burninated. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[yes-no](/questions/tagged/yes-no) [same](/questions/tagged/same) [huge](/questions/tagged/huge) [issues](/questions/tagged/issues) and [old](/questions/tagged/old)  are burninated.

[image: All hail Trogdor!]

feeling like a **NINJA.**

Answer (score 10):

[yes-no](/questions/tagged/yes-no) is used for different purposes: from boolean fields, to dialog boxes, GUI elements, yes/no questions, and boolean settings. It is used with too many purposes to be useful, and in most of the cases knowing that the question is, for example, about yes/no questions rather than other type of questions is not relevant.

[old](/questions/tagged/old) is used to generically say the question is about something old, which is not relevant for a question. Would we tag [old](/questions/tagged/old) all the Drupal 5 questions, or any questions about a old version of any software?

[huge](/questions/tagged/huge) is used when the question is about something extremely large. It doesn't seem relevant, except for mathematic about large numbers, but for that there is already [biginteger](/questions/tagged/biginteger).

[same](/questions/tagged/same) doesn't add anything to questions. Probably there are better tags to use, such as [clone](/questions/tagged/clone), [database-cloning](/questions/tagged/database-cloning), or [jquery-clone](/questions/tagged/jquery-clone), if they apply to the question.

Those tags should be burninated, but I would first check the questions using [huge](/questions/tagged/huge) to see which ones could be tagged [biginteger](/questions/tagged/biginteger).

Comment: I see many questions in `huge` that refer to big databases. I suppose `bigdata` could serve for those?

Comment: [tag:largenumbers]? Don't you mean [tag:biginteger]?

Comment: I don't know from where I took that tag. `:)`