# homework tag reapplied

Tags: discussion, edits, homework, tags

The homework tag [has been deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?newsletter=1&nlcode=95043|8eb5). I was going through some homework questions and noticed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12480464/revisions): the homework tag has been removed and the question closed but someone edited the post and put the homework tag back.

- How can someone put a tag on a question when that tag has been deleted?
- What is the best approach to that kind of situation? Should I just roll back the latest edit?

ps: someone has rolled back in the meantime.

Comment: The tag has not been deleted. It should simply no longer be used. That doesn't mean it can't technically still be used.

Comment: I just tried to flag a HW question and noticed this. Why is the tag deprecated. It would seem to be very useful for both filtering content and the nature of the answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The tag has not been deleted: it is being removed manually. We're doing it manually because a lot of questions tagged [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) need some clean up, usually in the form of editing or closing.

If you notice someone adding the tag, please point them politely to the new policy. Note that you can address the editor of a post with the `@` notation in a comment (the autocompletion won't pick up the name for you, but the editor will be notified). This is the comment I've been leaving:

> `@NameOfEditor Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).`

If you notice someone engaging in a rollback war (i.e. you remove the homework tag, and the same person comes and adds it back), flag the post for moderator attention and describe what is going on.

Comment: +1 Not everyone on Stack Overflow pays attention to Meta or the tag wiki excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

I *was* tempted to make a sarcastic comment but I'm attempting to grow as a person (failing) so how about a constructive suggestion instead?

Why not make [Tim's Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) <sup>1</sup> [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)?

It'll bring more people into help clean-up the tag and most should be able to help. With the suggested edit queue being kept so low then even if low rep users go mad it should be fine (unless of course some people go approval crazy).

<sup>1. See what I did there?</sup>

Comment: I'd be afraid of low-rep users. Last time we did a tag cleanup everyone just approved all the crap "removed one tag" edits that didn't improve other *blatantly* obvious issues and were coming in faster than they could be approved. At 20,000 strong, I'd rather let people who visit Meta enough to see it help out, as they tend to care a little more about quality versus just editing for the reputation.

Comment: I remember, that's why I added the caveat; not sure about it myself but it is a way of letting people know.