# Spelling error in community bulletin

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

The front page (and other pages) says:

> Community Bulletin
>   event
>   The homework tag is officially depreciated – ends Oct 9

and it links to [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1)

"deprecated" is misspelled as "depreciated."

Comment: It's definitely bottomed out

Comment: This is a dup, but I cannot seem to find the original.

Comment: The spell checker wins again!

Answer (score 4):

Typo? What typo? =)