# Request for a homework Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request

Since the [homework tag was recently burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/162577) would it make sense to create a Stack Exchange site dedicated to homework help? It wouldn't have to be limited strictly to homework either, possibly including discussions of puzzles and brain teasers and possible approaches to solving them.

I have a programming background so I would be interested in helping with CS or math related homework, discussions of programming contest problems, etc. Topics don't necessarily have to be related to programming either. That's just where my interests are.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Wow, I feel like I'm back on usenet.

Comment: @Dave Since this is your first time on Meta, note that [voting is a bit different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) here than on the main site.

Comment: For asking a question that is topically relevant on two groups and getting my hand slapped for picking the wrong one.

Comment: Yeah, meta sites can require a completely different mindset about what reputation is.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone. It's where groups of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like Stack Overflow. Here you can:
>
> - Propose new Q&A sites. If you have an idea for an expert Q&A site, propose it here.
> - Get involved in the process. Help sites get off the ground by defining the types of questions that are wanted, recruiting a critical mass of experts, and committing to the site's success.

There's already a [homework proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44531/stack-overflow-homework):

> #### Stack Overflow - Homework
>
> Proposed Q&A site for not to be confused with the closed Homework Help proposal, this covers the same topic matter as Stack Overflow but with restrictions on how specific answers are.

It's too early to tell whether it will make it to beta or not, but if you are interested you should follow the proposal and perhaps contribute a few example questions. If you are interested in answering (and asking) computer science questions, homework or not, you should also check out [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Keep in mind that it's the homework tag we're trying to kill, not homework questions. Homework questions are welcome on Stack Overflow, provided they follow the normal guidelines.