# Site to ask questions/discuss about homework?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange community can I use to ask questions or discuss about homework?

I did try the homework exercise myself (it's about setting up a virtual network by the way), but my trials didn't work out as expected (it gives me an error), so what I want is a hint to push me in the right direction, and of course not to let you make the homework for me

Comment: You mean, you want to ask your homework question? *Homework for education* isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean and I changed it :)

Comment: Nowhere.  Just because your question contains absolutely no clue as to the subject of the homework, thus indicating the quality of questions forthcoming.

Comment: "about homework"? ...about assigning homework? for help with homework? Are you asking about a specific subject? ... [Mathematics Educators](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) comes to mind

Comment: How about a sample of the kind of question you would ask?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request for a homework Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148595/request-for-a-homework-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: About homework _itself_? Assigning it? Doing it? Getting away with not doing it? Its spiritual ramifications in a postcapitalist society? Or about about a problem you happen to have been assigned _on some particular subject_? This is completely unclear from your question.

Comment: I did try the homework exercise myself (it's about setting up a virtual network by the way), but my trials didn't work out as expected (it gives me an error)

Comment: Then ask a good question about the error. A good question is a good question no matter if it is about homework or not. That something is homework doesn't mean that one should get a free pass for asking a low quality question.

Comment: I asked it but, some users already think it's about a homework exercise

Answer (score 8):

Homework questions are acceptable in [Chem](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), and [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com), as long as:

1. The OP shows effort in answering the questions he had. This is to prevent homework dumps from reducing the quality of the questions on the site.
2. They're about chemistry/math/physics, which means the answer will involve those concepts.

For more info about how the trilogy responds to homework, read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

For the physics/chem homework policy, see [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). And see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/a-consolidated-homework-policy) regarding the math.SE homework policy.