# Repseekers and homework questions

Tags: discussion

There are lots of discussions on SO about homework, both in question comments and here on meta, there are even a very good answer on the homework guidelines...

Also the homework tag is deprecated.

And finally, there are lots of high reputation regulars that complain of homework questions.

Yet I keep seeing some high reputation people that are called by others as "repwhores" that not only reply homework questions, but instead of putting explanation, they just put the full answer, usually if the question is asking to write a program, some people paste a full complete program that is just matter of the student copying and pasting and showing to the teacher.

Why students should not post homework here, when there are people here willing to their homework for them? We have no right to complain about homework questions, downvote them or close them, if representatives of SO community with 20k+ rep people do their homework for them without any punishment or even a warning from the rest of the community.

Worse than the students that come to ask questions here in good faith, it is those that just to get reputation do their homework for them, because it is a easy way to give a precise technical answer, and other SO users upvote these (even if they downvote the question).

EDIT: This is NOT a proposal. I am only seeing a problem, and I don't know how to fix it.

Problem: homework questions bother people on SO (because most of them are low quality, and those that aren't bother peopel anyway, since they get downvoted quickly). Yet people put answers on them of the sort that encourage students to put their homework here.

I believe in two approaches: One, is make it clear that homework questions are fine, and should not be downvoted just for being homework.

The other, is make it clear that doing homework for those who ask is not good, and that they should suffer some punishment (maybe downvoting at least).

Comment: What is your question? Or are you just venting?

Comment: Academic honesty is something that entirely falls upon the student. It is not something that we can be held responsible for. I would personally not answer a question in full detail if I have an hunch it might be homework, but that is my choice.

Comment: We (community) should not behave with less double standard regarding that? If we complain about homework questions, don't tolerate those that encourage those questions. If we tolarate those, then we should stop complaining about the questions.

Comment: What are you proposing here? Are you proposing anything? Where do you want to take this discussion?

Comment: My personal opinion is that we should devise a way to punish reputation seekers that just plomp down full code on homework, or at least develop clear guidelines for that, that we can point to them.

Comment: That's just nonsense. If it's academic honesty you're worried about, then that's up to the student. Other than that, you're talking about regular questions which happen to be homework. If it's a good question, it's welcome. If it's not a good question, it should be closed. And we have many users answering low-hanging fruit for rep, equally as much for non-homework questions. Should they be punished as well?

Comment: Well, make your proposals in the question. Dribbling out half formed ideas in comments is no good.

Comment: I am talking about double-standards and hypocrysy, I see people complaining that homework questions exist, and then giving full answers on them, encouraging people to post more of those questions (many in low quality). If you don't want those questions, don't give answers that encourage them.

Comment: @speeder in your response to your last edit, I am pretty sure it was finally decided (as a community) that [homework questions were permitted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) as long as they met quality standards, and half-assed non-answers to point the asker in the right direct were not quality answers and should be treated as such.

Comment: Then why some good homework questions get downvoted to oblivion anyway?

Comment: Show me proof of that. Show me a good question which got downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: This question could be better, but -6 I think it is too much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056046/how-do-i-output-the-numbers-which-the-variable-is-divisable-with

Comment: @speeder fyi... The hypocrites and double standard bearers don't like it when you point out that they're hypocrites and double standard bearers.  You just get down-voted for stating that fact.  I do feel your pain, tho

Comment: That's a hopeless question. It fails to actually ask a question. It states a problem and dumps a wall of code. It deserves -6. The answers attempt to help. That's commendable. I see no problem here.

Comment: @speeder That is a pretty poor question. The user doesn't state what the problem is, but merely what he wants. "What kind of syntax should I use" is not a good question. If this is your example of a great homework question which should not have been downvoted, then I do not agree.

Comment: @ChrisGerken What hypocrisy or double standard is in place here? Also, just "stating that fact" is pointless unless you're suggesting a solution, so I see nothing wrong with downvoting a question that just complains. This question has been edited to suggest two alternatives for fixing the problem towards the end, which is great.

Comment: Can we please stop with the "repwhore" name calling? Reputation exists to turn selfish behavior toward a result that benefits the community. Any one of us who has checked our reputation score is a "repwhore".

Comment: @BradLarson: "*Reputation exists to turn selfish behavior toward a result that benefits the community.*" That's the theory, at any rate. In practice, there are things people do to increase rep that don't benefit the community at all. That's where "repwhore" accusations come on: when someone is doing something that increases rep at the *expense* of making the site better.

Comment: @speeder, as a colleague is fond of saying, "The community doesn't exist, each one of us is all there is". This is an anarchy, there is no way of getting everybody here to agree on how to behave. But yes, homework questions are an easy way of gathering reputation, and some of us are easy to tempt. But there isn't any way to "fix" that...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think we've outgrown the homework question stigma. The intentions behind questions or answers cannot be known with certainty, so guessing at them is pointless. Whether a person is "repwhoring" or genuinely trying to seek/give help is not something you need to know when judging the quality of a post.

If a question provides a platform for information that will be useful to future users, it is a good question. If an answer provides this information with clarity and succinctness, it is a good answer. The intentions of the users are irrelevant.

> ...but instead of putting explanation, they just put the full
>   answer, usually if the question is asking to write a program, some people paste a full complete program...

Then you should downvote the answer, because a code dump is a bad answer on any question, not just homework questions.

> We have no right to complain about homework questions

Absolutely correct. Do not complain about a question simply because the OP is seeking help with homework. Complain about a question if it is poorly researched, unreadable or off topic.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter why someone answers a question. If the person answering is motivated to answer because they think the answer will garner reputation, that is fine. If the answer is deemed helpful and valuable, it will be upvoted.

There is nothing wrong with rep seekers. If they gain reputation from answering questions, so what? Typically rep seekers help people. That's what SO is all about.

In the same way, it doesn't matter why someone asks a question. Whether or not the question is a homework problem is neither here nor there. Questions should be judged on their intrinsic merits, and not on the motivation behind the asking of the question..

Comment: Not if their behaviour encourage bad questions.

Comment: Then close or delete the questions if they deserve it.

Comment: @speeder No, the motivation of the person answering is simply irrelevant. If an answer is good it will be upvoted. If it is bad it will be down voted. If a question is good it will be upvoted. If it is bad it will be downvoted and close voted. Whether an answerer seeks rep is simply  irrelevant.

Comment: @speeder Your acceptance of Asad's excellent answer which I upvoted seems at odds with your comment to this answer.

Comment: He fully understood my point.

Comment: @speeder He said the same as me, albeit he said it better.

Comment: The part that he said the same as you, it is the same, what he understood is that people should not downvote homework just for being homework, and that complete code without good explanations should not be upvoted either.

Comment: I agree, questions should not be downvoted just because they are homework, and code only answers are not good. If you read my postings in the delphi tag on SO you'll discover that I am a vehement advocate for answers with explanation rather than code only answers.

Answer (score 3):

It's not StackOverflow's job to regulate/moderate "cheating", and I think it's fair to say:

- asking someone else to do your homework for you in its entirety *is* cheating.

The onus* is on course directors and assessors (if they care).

** Mainly, the student is doing themselves a disservice, will most likely will find all subsequent homeworks more difficult without understanding this one, **and that's their problem**... they won't have StackOverflow in their exam!*

Comment: It's _onus_, not _impetus_ /nitpick

Comment: @EugeneSeidel onus is clearly better, but I think both are ok...? Edited!