# Self-made solutions or library-based solutions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When a user asks something like

> How can I accomplish X?

Should he (be forced to?) specify whether he wants a hint on an algorithm, or a pointer to a library function that might help him do what he/she is asking?

Comment: He should be providing an example of what he's tried so we can *help him solve an actual problem* and not just do everything for him.

Comment: @animuson, how is your comment related to my question?

Comment: The homework tag is burned, blacklisted, and *never* to return. [Linky for your meta fun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @l19 I'm saying neither of the options you provided are valid options. That would not be considered a good question, and it should be closed.

Comment: @KenWhite, I know that the question is no good, it's just an example...

Comment: Please see the OP, I've edited. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @l19: I know what you're asking, and my answer would be the same. :-) In fact, I've posted it as one.

Answer (score 7):

When a user asks a question like this, it should be downvoted mercilessly until it disappears, because it "shows no research effort; it is unclear or not useful", just like the popup over the downvote arrow indicates.

[image]

The question includes no salvageable content, and is clearly not useful to future readers in its current state.